# Bounded set in a finite dimensional space is relatively compact

Tags: functional-analysis

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely finite rank operators. In the text, the author gives the following *important* remark:

> **Remark A**: Every bounded operator of finite rank is a compact operator because it maps the unit ball to a bounded set in a finite dimensional subspace which is always relatively compact$^{[1]}$.

I know that an operator is compact if and only if it maps the unit ball to a relatively compact set. Thus, my questions really becomes fairly straightforward: why is a bounded set in a finite dimensional subspace always relatively compact?

---

$^{[1]}$ Note here that a set $K$ is said to be relatively compact if and only if every sequence $x_n\in K$ has a Cauchy subsequence $x_{n_k}\in K$.

Comment: [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem)?

Answer (score 2):

Because of Heine-Borel's theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$: every closed and bounded set is compact.

Comment: Together with the fact that any two norms on a finite-dimensional real vector space are equivalent.

Comment: The original question is norm-free; it is valid for general topological vector spaces.